# Tag synonym request [boot-failure]->[boot]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

I don't have the necessary score to propose [boot-failure](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/boot-failure)->[boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/boot), so could someone with the necessary score please propose it? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I don't think the two are synonymous though. Booting (in general) and boot-failure are significantly different enough to necessitate different tags.

Comment: Fair point. [filler filler]

Comment: Yeah but tags are based on rough generalizations on what people would subscribe to, not be so specific.